# Tangent spaces at different points in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry

In the book [Theoretical Physics](https://www.amazon.fr/Theoretical-Physics-Jean-Claude-Dutailly/dp/1539889432) by J. C. Dutailly the author says

> However because the manifolds are actually affine spaces, in SR and
> Galilean Geometry the tangent spaces at different points share the same
> structure (which is the underlying tangent vector space), and only in
> these cases they can be assimilated to $\mathbb R^4$: This is the origin of much
> confusion on the subject, and the motivation to start in the GR
> context where the concepts are clearly diferentiated.

My question is what does the author mean that tangent spaces at different points share the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking in 3D language: he means that the tangent plane of a plane is the plane itself (or rather parallel to it), and so is usually not identified as a separate entity. On the other hand, a tangent plane to a sphere is usually immediately recognized as having an important meaning because it depends on the point where the tangent plane is determined.